# Dynamic navigation bar in ember.js with different routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a dynamic navigation bar in ember. I have a partial header included in application template which have an element 'search' that should be only visible when I get to my events index route. I have tried to do that this way:

```
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  eventsIndexController: Ember.inject.controller 'events/index'
  isSearchActive: Ember.computed 'eventsIndexController.showSearch', ->
    @get 'eventsIndexController.showSearch'
```

And in events index controller:

```
EventsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  showSearch: false
```

When it gets to events index route

```
EventsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ...

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('model', model)
    controller.set('showSearch', true)
  deactivate: ->
    @controllerFor('events.index').set('showSearch', false)
```

And it works fine - model is set properly and search option is only visible in events index route. The problem is that I would like to perform some action when search is clicked but since this action is declared in **EventsIndexController** I can't call it in normal way from application template. So my first question is:

- do you know how to achieve that?

And second question is:

- how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do in better way because it
  doesn't seem to be very clear way and it might get really complicated
  in a course of time when I'll need new dynamic segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already injected your `EventsIndexController` into the `ApplicationController`, you can handle the search click there and then trigger the desired action on the injected controller using the `send` method.

```
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    eventsIndexController: Ember.inject.controller('events/index'),
    actions: {
        searchClicked: function() {
            this.get('eventsIndexController').send('searchClicked');
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can directly invoke a method on the injected controller.